# How can i make my custom AppCompatActivity class for some function?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, project

I  want to make a custom class  AppCompatActivity there I can add my basic function and methods like hiding soft keyboard, hiding progress bar, and other methods that going to be used in the whole project constantly.

Comment: This is called a “BaseActivity” and it’s generally considered a bad design because over-reliance on inheritance makes code very unmanageable. Much better to create utility functions for this purpose. Just put the features you want to use in multiple activities into a function (or functions) and call it in `onCreate()` of each activity that needs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally those utilities functions don't need an Activity to hold them, instead they will be put on another file: `utils/ActivityUtils.java`.

Here is an example in an Android Java project: https://github.com/Blankj/AndroidUtilCode/blob/master/lib/utilcode/src/main/java/com/blankj/utilcode/util/ActivityUtils.java

And in Kotlin:
https://github.com/inusedname/Todo-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vstd/todo/others/utilities/ActivityUtils.kt